# Why typeof(HttpResponseMessage) is null?

Tags: c#, typeof, httpresponsemessage

We have our own tool to create documentation of our web api. It reads the `///` comments and creates the documentation from them. But we have one weird issue with it: The expression `typeof(HttpResponseMessage)` weirdly evaluates to `null`. Why this happens?

Just to clarify: When we read the assemblies at runtime and create documenation, we have `HttpResponseMessage` in `MethodInfo.ReturnType` of some API methods. This one works without problem. But when we try to check if the type is `HttpResponseMessage`, we do `if(methodInfo.ReturnType == typeof(HttpResponseMessage)` and here the right side of this if always evaluates to `null`. When I run it in Visual Studio debugger and write `typeof(HttpResponseMessage)` to Watch window, it evaluates to `null` too.

(The type is defined in `System.Net.Http`.)

Here is the screenshot from debugger showing that this is real:
[image]

The sceenshot clearly shows that typeof returns null both in program and in Watch window, but parameterType variable actually points to the type object of that class. It is a normal Win32 console application.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. I would be very surprised to see `typeof(HttpResponseMessage)` actually return null. It's entirely possible that there are debugger issues going on here though - it would be better if your example assigned the value to a variable, and compared that with null.

Comment: `typeof(HttpResponseMessage)` returning null is unfortunately harder to believe than user error.  I'd like to see a [mcve] demonstrating this issue.  AFAIK, `typeof(x)` can only return null if the class in question is a dynamic class created in memory.  That isn't the case here.

Comment: [Further reading: `typeof(T)` may return null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6497570/typeoft-may-return-null)

Comment: I added the screenshot from the VS debugger.

Comment: @Amy: I am not sure if your  link applies to this case, because this is neither generic nor dynamically generated type. Or am I wrong?

Comment: @AlKepp The takeaway is that `typeof` only works for types that exist at compile-time.  Types created at runtime don't apply.  I'm aware this doesn't apply in your case, I said as much in my first comment.

Comment: How are you reading the assemblies? Are you doing something weird like loading some with `ReflectionOnly`?

Comment: Will other types from the same assembly behave similarly, for example, will `typeof(System.Net.Http.HttpContent)` also look like null? Do you have several versions of this assembly? You still need to give us a full reproducible sample. With [this tio.run code](https://tio.run/##hYwxDsIwDEX3nMJjMpALoE5dGCgDDMzBGBQU4qg2lSrUs4cIde/yh/efHsoOBWsVDRoRMAUR6M3XrGDieIchxGxdg1MYQaEDnQvxw15mUXr7E6k/qJb/nEkKZ6GBRMKT3N6sVt8oJ/LXMSodYybbSh3kT0qbkuXbi1DdptzOxSy1/gA), everything seems normal.

Comment: Again, a screenshot from a debugger isn't as useful as a [mcve]. There's a *lot* that can happen in the Watch window that doesn't behave the same way elsewhere, and if we can't reproduce it that makes it a lot harder to help too.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I hit a strange edge case here. The typeof operator returns null on types imported from System.Net.Http assembly which is referenced in the project, but the file is in C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies which I think is not used to search assemblies in runtime. And the reference is set as CopyLocal=false. So it seems the issue is caused by the type being available at compile time, but not at run time. I would expect an exception if a type is missing and couldn't be loaded at runtime, but wow this operator just throws nulls silently.

I will test tomorrow if I can fix the issue by correcting this ill reference.